# How to use Entity Framework 6 to migrate database to local SQL Server from network server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I got a ASP.NET MVC 5 project which is already published in a server. But I have to extend it. Thus I'm trying to make local development environment with local database. I don't want to loss any data which is already working. As this is huge project. So all model and controller is done.

I'm also not an expert in ASP.NET world. After searching for a while I found there is way called code first approach.

As I have all the model so I'm assuming it should be able to make all local database in my machine.

The actual project connection strings looks like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="Name.DataSourceConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=test.test.com;User ID=myUser;Password=myPass" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

So for local machine I updated as:-

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="My TEST" 
         connectionString="Data Source= 192.168.1.12;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=dev;Password=dev" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I got project source and build and launch the service locally. When I try to logged in I get following error:-

> The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Note that same login is working fine in server.

Then I follow the link.

In package management console I insert command enable-migrations and then update-database -Force. I got following error:-

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I have SQL Server 2012 Express installed. I suspect my connection string is not defined correctly. How do I define it? Also any suggestion how to have local set-up development environment for working ASP.NET service?

Answer (score 0):

```
connectionString="Server=myip;Port=3306;Database=mydatabase;Uid=admin;Pwd=password;"
```

you could try this maybe you missing port and select database don't know how many database is configure in your mssql server.

Answer (score 0):

Code First, despite its name, can either create a new database or work with an existing database. However, and this is key, it cannot both create and manage tables and work with existing tables in the same database (at least not with the same context).

You can have multiple contexts, but they must be entirely segregated, i.e. they can't reference entities tracked by a different context or they'll attempt to take control of those entities away from that other context.

Long and short, if you have an existing database that you need to work with, Code First migrations are pretty much out the window. You can create new entity types, but you'll need to create the tables for them manually in your database.

As far as just get a local copy goes, though, all you need to do is take a backup of the production DB and restore it locally. It really has nothing to do with Entity Framework or MVC.